# Why CXF won't annotate bare parameter with @XmlJavaAdapter?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf, wsd

**About problem**

I use Wsdl2Java to generate java classes from wsdl file. Jaxb throws exception "unknown unmarshaller" when using generated web service interface.
The problem exists in operations where their input parameter is an element of xs:dateTime type, such as this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="asd:asd"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="DateSinceStart" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

and JAXB has binding:

```
<globalBindings>
    <javaType
            name="java.time.LocalDateTime"
            xmlType="xs:dateTime"
            parseMethod="LocalDateTimeAdapter.unmarshal"
            printMethod="LocalDateTimeAdapter.marshal"/>
</globalBindings>
```

Jaxws binding:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
    <!-- Disable default wrapper style -->
    <enableWrapperStyle>false</enableWrapperStyle>
</bindings>
```

Then, the generated MyServiceInterface.java takes the LocalDateTime as input argument. JaxB throws exception from unmarshall method, as unmarshaller is unknown to context.

**What I expect from generator**

In MyServiceInterface.java file, generator should add `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1.class)` line above the LocalDateTime input parameter.
Manual insertion works and makes JAXB is able to understand how to unmarshall this type:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "asd:asd", name = "MyServiceInterface")
@XmlSeeAlso({asd.asd.ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface MyServiceInterface {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "Operation", action = "asd:asd:#Operation")
    @WebResult(name = "OperationResponse", targetNamespace = "asd:asd", partName = "OperationResponseBody")
    public asd.asd.OperationResponseType operation(
        @WebParam(partName = "OperationBody", name = "DateSinceStart", targetNamespace = "asd:asd")
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1.class)
        java.time.LocalDateTime operationBody
    );
}
```

**Question**

**Why generator can't insert annotation automatically? Is it bug in framework?**

Note: if parameter is wrapped by request class, `@XmlJavaAdapter` is placed correctly above corresponding field.

**Context**

Below I paste contract files just to get idea of my problem:

MyService.wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:tt="asd:asd"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  name="MyService"
  targetNamespace="asd:asd">
  <wsdl:documentation>
    <ServiceName>MyService</ServiceName>
    <Version>1</Version>
  </wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="asd:asd">
      <xsd:include schemaLocation="Operation.xsd"/>
      <xsd:include schemaLocation="OperationResponse.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="OperationMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tt:DateSinceStart" name="OperationBody"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="OperationResponseMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tt:Response" name="OperationResponseBody"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="MyServiceInterface">
    <wsdl:operation name="Operation">
      <wsdl:input message="tt:OperationMessage" name="OperationIn">
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tt:OperationResponseMessage" name="OperationOut">
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="MyServiceBinding" type="tt:MyServiceInterface">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="Operation">
      <soap:operation soapAction="asd:asd:#Operation"/>
      <wsdl:input name="OperationIn">
        <soap:body parts="OperationBody" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="OperationOut">
        <soap:body parts="OperationResponseBody" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding> 
  <wsdl:service name="MyService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tt:MyServiceBinding" name="MyService">
      <soap:address location="http://address"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Operation.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="asd:asd"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="DateSinceStart" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

I don't paste OperationResponse.xsd content, because it contains element of xs:complexType, and all dateTimes have `@XmlJavaAdapter` annotation at corresponding LocalDateTime field. Complex types are just all right.

Comment: Have you checked out `wsimport` instead of `wsdl2java`? I prefer using that tool, because of those little things. I am not sure if this is a bug or not, but give a chance to the other jdk tool.

Comment: Not yet, but I'll give it a try since wsdl2java seems not doing it's job quite well...